# Gather System information using .Net web Application from Mac and Windows PC

Tags: javascript, .net, windows, macos

In one of my project i have to gather full system information (hardware and software) of desktop (Windows and Mac).

While searching i found can use WMI in .net to gather windows system information and code samples are also available at codeproject.com

But i cannot manage to find how to gather system information from mac pc using website application.

Is it possible to gather system information using .net or javascript for Mac PC.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get "full system information" without executing deployed code to the target machines (or at least breaks outside the browser sandbox).
I need to clarify that, as it seems you have the impression that you think the .NET WMI code can run in a web application and query anybody who browses to it.

Also, the [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) stands for **Windows** Management Instrumentation, and that ends the hope for getting it running on a Mac.

I think your best bet is looking at [WBEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-Based_Enterprise_Management).

Comment: Thanks Magnus for quick reply i am checking more samples and information about WBEM on google and come back with any queries i have.